# opted out of internal traffic but real time tracking still shows me as connected

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I’ve followed the advice by Google as to how to go about setting a cookie to block internal (my own) traffic to a site I’m building. See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#optout

I’ve followed this to the letter using this code:

```
<p>Opt-out of Google Analytics</p>

<a href="javascript:gaOptout()" class="button action">Opt-out now</a>

<script>
  // Set to the same value as the web property used on the site
  var gaProperty = 'UA-xxxxxxx-x';

  // Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists.
  var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
  if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
    window[disableStr] = true;
  }

  // Opt-out function
  function gaOptout() {
    document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
    window[disableStr] = true;
  }
</script>
```

My browser is showing this cookie as having been set. When I go to Google Analytic and check ‘real time’ traffic however, I can see that I’m registered as viewing the site (I’m 99.9% sure it’s me due to the location and the fact the site is new and doesn’t get any traffic, and I’ve checked with mobile and tablet connections as well). Surely Google Analytics shouldn’t be able to see me viewing the site at all now? It feels like it’s not working properly...

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Does anyone have a better way of opting out of internal traffic when the IP is dynamic?

Comment: Most reliable way is the opt-out plugin. However your solution should work. How long since you implemented this (GA realtime will show you for 30 minutes after your last interaction because that's how it takes until your session runs out, even if no more data is collected).

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it could be the 30 minute thing, I kinda assumed analytics would just immediately stop showing as soon as the cookie is downloaded to browser. I’ll take another look, thanks.

Comment: I've tried the same script, but after one day, when I visit another page, Real time analytics still shows not sure why.